# Wordpress wp insert post function inserting on another host, not in localhost

Tags: database, wordpress, insert

I have an issue with wp_insert_post function of wordpress. I want to insert on a wordpress database not locating in localhost. Im not sure that i can config this function to point to another IP database.

It seems that it takes the values of wp-config and inserts in the database that file points to.

Any suggestion or idea, please?

Thanks.

Comment: wp_insert_post and all other wp functions regarding DB only manipulates the DB specified in the config. have you tried sending POST data to the other host and save it on it's own (other site, not the local) DB?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As i thought, the function only operates in own database. Umm yes i can consider your option, my second idea was making a query of the local posts and inserting in the other database. For that i establish 2 databases connections using MySQL ODBC Driver.

Thanks !!

Comment: you mean you'll have a different mysqli_connect for the remote DB?

Comment: here is some solution : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257757/save-custom-post-type-to-external-database/417401#417401

Answer (score 0):

Final Answer: wp_insert_post only works for wordpress own database.

My solution was really easy: I have just moved my php file to the remote machine and run from it, so the function worked correctly.

Additionally I created a MySQL ODBC connection in odbcad32.exe for the other wordpress database and made a query of all the posts (select * from wp_posts). Them got the data and called the wp_insert_function filling the array of parameters. Not difficult.

Thanks for the feedbacks !!